# SSRS: prevent word break on plus and minus signs

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

I've got textbox in SSRS report. Textbox consists of 2 placeholders. Second one is long enough for line to be split several times. I want text to be wrapped on spaces, but it's wrapped on plus and minus signs instead. I need "a-b+" and "Ss-+" to be kept together.

[image: Actual output]

Text is fetched from database, I have full control but can't predict exact length or particular order.

My guess is that engineers who've implemented wrapping thought of plus and minus signs as a part of math formula. That's wrong in my case.

So far I've tried to add HTML tags:  makes each block occupy whole line and  makes no effect. I need something like *display: inline-block*

I've tried creating several placeholders for each non-breaking value - no effect.

If I replace plus and minus signs with letters, placeholder wraps text just fine:

[image: Desired output]

One obvious solution would be to calculate required character length to add manual line breaks (vbcrlf). But it can't be done easily since it's not a monospaced font.

Is it possible to prevent word wrapping on plus and minus signs?

Comment: What output format used for the report? Do you view in the browser, or export to some other format?

Comment: We export to PDF in production. Output is the same in BIDS and in PDF.